# Can't the inheritance method inherit the return statement?

Tags: python, inheritance

```
class Student(object):
    def __init__(self, name='', age=18, score=[]):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.score = score

    def total_score(self):
      *  total = sum(self.score)
      *  return total


class Undergraduate(Student):
    def __init__(self, name='', age=18, score=[], major=''):
        super().__init__(name, age, score)
        self.major = major

    def total_score(self):
        super().total_score()


stu1 = Undergraduate(name='李四', age=21, score=[100, 98, 99], major='大数据')
print(stu1.total_score())
```

The result is None. And if I change the code at the `*` sign to `print(sum(self.score))`, I can get the result I want. I wonder why.

Comment: `Undergraduate.total_score` does not have any return statement, so it returns None.

Comment: There is no need to define `total_score` for `Undergraduate` at all unless it does more than calling its parent's `total_score`.

Comment: Did you mean something like `return super().total_score()`?

Comment: You *overrode* your method. In the overriding method, you call the overriden method, `super().total_score()`, **that** method call evaluates to the return value, which you do nothing with. And the overriding method therefore returns `None` by default

Comment: I mean, why didn't it come back sum(self.score) of value.And let me output.

Comment: Because you're not `return`ing it from `Undergraduates.total_score`. Returns are always explicit, never implicitly inherited from somewhere else.